# Flying Saucer ignores counter-increment and counter-reset

Tags: php, css, symfony, flying-saucer, css-paged-media

I'm currently working with Symfony2 for PHP and SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle which uses Flying Saucer to generate PDFs.

I need to let the user input a starting number page to print a form with number pages. If I do something as simple as

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page 5;
    ...
    @top-right {
        content: counter(page);
    };
}
```

The generated PDF won't increment each page by 5. I'm doing this to test the functionality, as the intended code is

```
@page {
    ...
    @top-right {
        content: counter(page);
    };
}

@page:first {
    counter-increment: page {{ startingPage-1 }}; /* The last part is Twig code for printing the starting page dynamically */
}
```

Why is this happening?